# tableViewのセルを削除する際にfirestoreのドキュメントも削除したいのですが、ドキュメントIDの取得方法がわかりません。

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

現在、パスワード管理アプリを制作しています。
入力された値をfirestoreに追加して、TableViewに表示するところまでできました。
次に、選択されたTableViewのセルを削除する機能を製作中なのですが、その時にfirestoreのデータ（ドキュメント）も削除したいです。

[公式ドキュメント](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data?authuser=0) の通りにドキュメントを削除するコードを書いてみたのですが、ドキュメントIDの取得方法がわかりません。

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MypageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    var displayData: [Data] = []
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        emailLabel.text = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
        db.collection("passwordData").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if let recorder = data["recorder"] as? String, let service = data["service"] as? String, let password = data["password"] as? String {
                        if recorder == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
                            let cellData = Data(title: service, password: password, recorder: recorder)
                            self.displayData.append(cellData)
                            print(self.displayData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.displayData.count - 1, section: 0)
                                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func selectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UITableView.ScrollPosition) {
        print(indexPath)
        print("選択されました")
    }
    
}

extension MypageViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.displayData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let passwords = displayData[indexPath.row]
        
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = passwords.password
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = passwords.title
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
        {
            return true
        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let id: Data = self.displayData[indexPath.row]
        
        
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            displayData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            db.collection("displayData").document("ここのIDの取得方法を教えていただけませんか？").delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully removed!")
                }
                print(id)
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

入力されたデータは、以下のコードでfirestoreに追加しています。

```
struct Data {
    var title: String
    var password: String
    var recorder: String
}

if let title = titleText.text, let password = diaryText.text, let account = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
            var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
            ref = db.collection("passwordData").addDocument(data: [
                "recorder": account,
                "service": title,
                "password": password,
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("succesfully!")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ドキュメントIDはデータの取得の際に取得できます。どうやってデータを取得していますか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。公式ドキュメントのスタートガイドに載っている通りに取得しました。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ただそれだと「公式ドキュメントのスタートガイド」を熟読しないと回答がかけないことになります。コードも追記していただいたようなのですが、データを取得する処理ではありません。今のままでは回答を書くことは難しいので、データ取得部分(特に`self.displayData`に値を入れる部分を詳しく)の情報を追加して見てください。

Comment: 返信していただき、ありがとうございます。追記したのは、データを追加する部分でしたね^^;取得する部分を追記します。

Comment: コードの追記ありがとうございます。コードの整形がうまく出来ていないようなので、今後もQ&Aサイトをご利用される可能性があるのであれば、きちんとやり方を覚えられた方がいいでしょう。(このサイトの場合、コードの先頭と最後に ``` だけの行を入れるだけです。)いただいた情報をもとに回答を書いてみるので、後ほどご確認ください。

Comment: 質問する側が、コードを普通に示せていないのは問題でしたね。やり方まで教えていただき、本当にありがとうございます！次からはきちんと整形していきます。

Comment: 質問に回答していただき、ありがとうございます！データの型から見直せばよかったのですね！本当に助かりました！！

Answer (score 0):

各ドキュメントを表すデータ型(あなたの場合`Data`、Swiftの標準ライブラリにある型名と全く同じ型名の定義があるとつまらないことで引っかかる可能性があるので、以下では`PasswordData`に変更してあります)に`documentID`を表すプロパティを追加するのが確実で簡単だと思います。

あなたのコードでは`FirebaseFirestoreSwift`モジュールをimportすると使えるようになる「カスタムオブジェクト」の機能は使っていないようなので、素直に`documentID`を取得して、所定のプロパティに設定してやるだけです。

```
struct PasswordData {
    var documentID: String
    var title: String
    var password: String
    var recorder: String
}
```

```
        db.collection("passwordData").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentID = doc.documentID //<-
                    let data = doc.data()
                    if let recorder = data["recorder"] as? String,
                       let service = data["service"] as? String,
                       let password = data["password"] as? String
                    {
                        if recorder == Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
                            let cellData = PasswordData(
                                documentID: documentID, //<-
                                title: service,
                                password: password,
                                recorder: recorder)
                            //...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

このようにしておけば、削除の時には削除される要素から`documentID`を取り出すだけです。

```
        let removed = displayData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        let documentID = removed.documentID
        //... `documentID`を使った削除処理
```